Blazor NotFound and NotAuthorized not working in .net 8
I'm facing an issue with .NET 8 and Blazor. The interactive render mode is set to Auto (Server and WebAssembly). The problem is when I add NotAuthorized and NotFound it fails to navigate to either my Login page or my NotFound page. Adding UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects allows me to navigate to one of the pages, but I want unauthorized requests to redirect to the login page and requests for non-existing pages to redirect to NotFound.
If the page doesn't exist, it will display the default browser error "page not found." If the page does exist and I'm not logged in, it will navigate to "account/login" instead of "/login," which is the path of my Login component.
Do you have any ideas on how to achieve this? I've searched the internet but couldn't find a full solution to my problem.
@using HTPB.Client.Pages
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization

<CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly }">
        <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Layout.MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                    <Login></Login>
                </NotAuthorized>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
        </Found>
        <NotFound>
            <NotFound></NotFound>
        </NotFound>
    </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>


The default template should configure all this when you create a new project with authentication. Have you tried this?

I did and it's not working as expected, or I did something wrong.

The project templates work. If they didn't, a lot of Blazor developers would have noticed, because even the tutorials would fail to run. Did you actually create a new project, with individual accounts, tried to run it and see it fail to redirect? Or did you try only after modifying the original code to something else?

@PanagiotisKanavos I'm encountering the same issue even if with a brand new Blazor Project... Do you discover anything about that???

I encounter the same issue. Maybe it is a bug from Microsoft. The template works, because they have the login page in account/login, but the tag NotAuthorized is not working as expected in Routes.razor. Maybe  it only works in IntersactiveServer rendermode but not in SSR.
I only found the work around to put my login page in account/login and move on.
@page "/account/login"
